# query to call stored procedure from data service created using wso2 application server

Tags: wso2

How to write a query to call a stored procedure having both an in and an out parameter using the data service which is created in the wso2 application.

I am using this query: `call wso2proc(:e_id,:e_name,?)`

and stored procedure is as below..

```
create or replace PROCEDURE WSO2PROC ( e_id IN emp20.id% TYPE , e_name IN emp20.name% TYPE , e_address OUT emp20.address% TYPE ) IS 
    BEGIN
        select address INTO e_address from emp20 e where e.id=e_id and e.name=e_name;
    END WSO2PROC;
```

Please suggest how to write the query while creating a data service in wso2 application server so that out parameter is returned.

Comment: To clarify- is there is one DSS server and one AS where has a service. And you want to get some data using DSS depending on some input provided my AS service. Am i correct in your scenario here.

Comment: I am using wso2 sb 4.0.6 now and created data service in browser which should get data from oracle data base using stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Shelan.
Got the answer.
Now I used this query .....> call wso2proc(?,?,?)
And given input mapping for all the in and out parameter name present in stored procedure's parameter with same name.
AS for example :
create or replace procedure wso2prc(name in varchar,address out varchar)

So given name as in and address as out in input-mapping with same name as present in above proc.
Apart of this I did out-mapping for address, which will come as a result from procedure.
And Its working.